# How to train test split and cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, cross-validation, train-test-split

I still  confuse about data validation workflow. As I understand, when I get a dataset, I split the data into two parts, training set and test set, using `train_test_split`. Then, I perform `cross_val_score` or`cross_val_predict` on training set for model selection and hyperparameter tuning. Then, I perform the selected model on test set to see the model performance. Am I understand correctly ? or I can perform `cross_val_score` and `cross_val_predict` on the entire dataset without using `train_test_split`

Comment: Please share as much details as possible while asking a question. What search have you done before asking this question ? Can you share any links where you have tried to search ? Which framework are you working with ? What is your dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , One can use  cross_val_score /cross_val_predict for model selection and parameter tuning. It also lets you choose metrics you want to judge the model on. So you basically choose your model and parameters after cross validation results  and see if it generalizes well with test data and real world data.